# Is there a way to export routes from Symfony2 bundle via DependencyInjection

Tags: routes, bundle, symfony

I want to automatically add routes from my bundle without adding a link to my bundle's routing scheme into routing.yml. For example, this can be admin's bundle. Each application that use this bundle will get special /admin/xxx routes without manual editing of routing scheme.

For services it's pretty easy with overriding of Extension->load() method, but for routing I couldn't find a solution.

How can I implement desired feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment you can't easily hook into the routing like that from a Bundle, that's why the framework stuff itself like the profiler and web debug toolbar have to be included from the routing_dev.yml file.

However it would be doable I believe to add an event dispatched when the routing is parsed I guess, allowing bundles to hook into it to add their own routes to the RouteCollection. I [created an issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1518) to that effect on the Symfony tracker.

Comment: Special event will be great for this, because many bundles will need to attach controllers to application. At the moment I decide to use listener for kernel.request event. This is only one automatic way to route requests to my bundle's controller.